# On composite solutions of $\operatorname{rad}(n-1)=\operatorname{rad}(\varphi(n))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, totient-function, arithmetic-functions

After I've read the statement of Lehmer's totient problem, see this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_totient_problem), I wondered what about composite solutions $n>4$ of the equation $$\operatorname{rad}(n-1)=\operatorname{rad}(\varphi(n)),$$

where $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function and with $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ we denote the radical of an integer, see in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer) this definition. I don't know if this equation was in the literature.

> **Question.** Is it know from the literature or your calculations if is there a composite number $n>4$ satisfying $$\operatorname{rad}(n-1)=\operatorname{rad}(\varphi(n))?$$ **Many thanks.**

There aren't examples for $4<n<50$. Additionally I've searched in  The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences the string *rad(phi(n))*.

Comment: If you write a computer program, you'll find lots of counterexamples. For example, the following values of $n$ yield counterexamples:
$$1729,\;2431,\;6601,\;9605,\;10585,\;12801,\;15211,\;30889$$

Comment: Please, if you want add your comment as an answer. Then I should to choose such as an answer. Many thanks @quasi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write a computer program, you'll find lots of counterexamples. For example, the following values of n
yield counterexamples:
$$1729,2431,6601,9605,10585,12801,15211,30889$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer one more time, and I believe that your sequence isn't in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.